# Static force layout in D3 v4

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

I am trying to reproduce [this example ("Static Force Layout" by Mike Bostock)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) in D3 v4.

I have combined Mike's code with what I learned while creating a dynamic force graph (which can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Federicopvs/8ce3840933bb44fbdeb1e95ae8d3f814)).

I (perhaps mistakenly) thought that making a static force graph would be easier, but I do not fully understand the logic of Mike's tutorial and I cannot "translate it to v4 language".

[This is how far I got.](http://bl.ocks.org/Federicopvs/7bbfc373d6f6ceb2f2524218f8a788e8)

In Mike's example each time the page is refreshed the nodes take a different position. My understanding is that the each tick operation moves each node randomly. Hence the position is determined (randomly) by this part of the code:

```
// Use a timeout to allow the rest of the page to load first.
setTimeout(function() {

// Run the layout a fixed number of times.
// The ideal number of times scales with graph complexity.
// Of course, don't run too long—you'll hang the page!
force.start();
for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
force.stop();

svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", 4.5);

loading.remove();
}, 10);
```

Where n is set arbitrarily.

This is how I translated that part:

```
setTimeout(function() {

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.ID; }))
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
        .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var n = 1000;
//I thought that since I have many nodes and edges in my graph I should use a highgher n. However, wheter n=10 or 1000 nothing changes in the final result

for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) simulation.tick();

simulation
  .nodes(data.nodes)
  .on('tick', ticked);

simulation.force('link')
  .links(data.edges)
  .distance(distance);

function ticked () {
    d3.selectAll('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius,  Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });

    d3.selectAll('line')
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });        
}   
//Strange fact: I need to have both this tick function and the position attributes for each node and edge for the visualization to show something.

simulation.stop();

var link = graph.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'links')
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(data.edges)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

var node = graph.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });

loading.remove();
}, 10);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2016-10-18**
*The stuff below about implementing a tick function being uncalled for seems totally incorrect from what I can tell after fiddling for another day or so.  I figured rather than just deleting the post I'd update it with my new understanding just for posterity.  To be clear, tick, from what I can tell, is indeed necessary to get the simulation to do anything with your objects.*

I'm working thru a similar problem right now and do not have a solution, but did notice one bit of code that may be worth reconsidering:

From the [on("tick", f(x)) doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_on):

> Note that tick events are not dispatched when simulation.tick is called manually; events are only dispatched by the internal timer and are intended for interactive rendering of the simulation. To affect the simulation, register forces instead of modifying nodes’ positions or velocities inside a tick event listener.

This all leads me to believe that the body of the following code is uncalled for, perhaps even incorrect:

```
function ticked () {
d3.selectAll('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius,  Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });

d3.selectAll('line')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
```

}

Hope that helps (I know this is old now, but who knows...)

Answer (score -1):

you need to stop and restart the simulation between calculating the end position:

```
    let _newNodes = null        
    const force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes);

    // bind listeners first
    force.on('tick', () => {
      const {nodes} = this.state;
      nodes.forEach(d => {  // keep within bounds
        d.x = Math.max(d.z, Math.min(this.props.width - d.z, d.x)); // incrementally derive bound x
        d.y = Math.max(d.z, Math.min(this.props.height - d.z, d.y)); // incrementally derive bound y
      });
      _newNodes = nodes;
    });

    // register force events
    force
      .force('y', d3.forceY(200).strength(0.01))
      // all of your configs here ...
      .stop();

    // calculate end state
    for (let i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(force.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - this.force.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
      force.tick();
    }
    // resume rendering
    force.restart();
```